# How to use websocket ReceiveAsync(Memory<byte>) and MemoryPool<byte>

Tags: c#, sockets, .net-core

I have a `ClientWebSocket` that is receiving blocks of data via the `ReceiveAsync(ArraySegment<byte> buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)` method:

```
while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open && cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested == false)
{
    var result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, cancellationToken);
    var isEndOfMessage = resultProcessor.Receive(result, buffer, out var frame);

    if (isEndOfMessage)
    {
        if (frame == null)
            break; // End of message with no data means socket closed - break.
        else
            await this.targetBlock.SendAsync(frame); // Process It.
    }
}
```

And I store partial frame chunks in a `ReadOnlySequence`:

```
public bool Receive(WebSocketReceiveResult result, ArraySegment<byte> buffer, out ReadOnlySequence<byte> frame)
{
    if (result.EndOfMessage && result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
    {
        frame = default;
        return false;
    }

    var slice = buffer
                    .Slice(0, result.Count)
                    .ToArray(); // Take a local copy to avoid corruption as buffer is reused by caller.

    if (startChunk == null)
        startChunk = currentChunk = new Chunk<byte>(slice);
    else
        currentChunk = currentChunk.Add(slice);
        
    if(result.EndOfMessage && startChunk != null)
    {
        if (startChunk.Next == null)
            frame = new ReadOnlySequence<byte>(startChunk.Memory);
        else
            frame = new ReadOnlySequence<byte>(startChunk, 0, currentChunk, currentChunk.Memory.Length);

        startChunk = currentChunk = null; // Reset so we can accept new chunks from scratch.
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        frame = default;
        return false;
    }
}
```

With the implementation of `ReadOnlySequenceSegment`:

```
class Chunk<T> : ReadOnlySequenceSegment<T>
{
    public Chunk(ReadOnlyMemory<T> memory)
    {
        Memory = memory;
    }
    public Chunk<T> Add(ReadOnlyMemory<T> mem)
    {
        var segment = new Chunk<T>(mem)
        {
            RunningIndex = RunningIndex + Memory.Length
        };

        Next = segment;
        return segment;
    }
}
```

With my current configuration, I am copying when going between `ArraySegment` and my chunk structure with a new array to avoid memory corruption (as the buffer gets continually overwritten by the socket).

I see the `webSocket.ReceiveAsync` alternative method that takes a `Memory<byte>`. I believe a high level process to use this paradigm would be:

1. Request a chunk of memory from a memory pool manager, have the `websocket.ReciveAsync` write to this rented memory
2. In the `WebSocketReceiveResultProcessor` function, link the memory into chunks (our `ReadOnlySequenceSegment` implementation)
3. Dispatch to application (i.e. decode json or similar)
4. Return the memory to the memory pool manager

Pseudo code below:

```
while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open && cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested == false)
{
    var buffer = memoryPoolManager.Rent();
    var result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, cancellationToken);

    // Modify the resultProcessor.Receive to receive Memory<byte> and return 
    // the same ReadOnlySequenceSegment implementation of Chunk chains.
    var isEndOfMessage = resultProcessor.Receive(result, buffer, out var frame);

    if (isEndOfMessage)
    {
        if (frame == null)
            break; // End of message with no data means socket closed - break.
        else
            await this.targetBlock.SendAsync(frame); // Process It.

        // Go through the loop of chunks and return back to the memory pool.
    }
}
```

I am looking for known github code for this dequeing/process using a websocket and clarification on the above process please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Memory buffer from pool is perfect solution because - you don't actually need those bytes for anything other than conversion or transfer. I mean, you either transform this data by zipping, encrypting, etc or deserialize it to some structured stream/object or just leave them as is and send them further in your app. Both case will be good with any array, be it from pool or new one in LOH. They will not be managing them, nor changing, just reading. In total - eliminate all ToArray() calls and use preallocated buffers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this working with the below helper functions:

```
class Chunk<T> : ReadOnlySequenceSegment<T>
{
    public Chunk(ReadOnlyMemory<T> memory)
    {
        Memory = memory;
    }
    public Chunk<T> Add(ReadOnlyMemory<T> mem)
    {
        var segment = new Chunk<T>(mem)
        {
            RunningIndex = RunningIndex + Memory.Length
        };

        Next = segment;
        return segment;
    }
}

sealed class WebSocketReceiveResultProcessor : IDisposable
{
    Chunk<byte> startChunk = null;
    Chunk<byte> currentChunk = null;
    private readonly bool isUsingArrayPool;

    public WebSocketReceiveResultProcessor(bool isUsingArrayPool)
    {
        this.isUsingArrayPool = isUsingArrayPool;
    }

    public bool Receive(WebSocketReceiveResult result, ArraySegment<byte> buffer, out ReadOnlySequence<byte> frame)
    {
        if (result.EndOfMessage && result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
        {
            frame = default;
            return false;
        }

        // If not using array pool, take a local copy to avoid corruption as buffer is reused by caller.
        var slice = isUsingArrayPool ? buffer.Slice(0, result.Count) : buffer.Slice(0, result.Count).ToArray();

        if (startChunk == null)
            startChunk = currentChunk = new Chunk<byte>(slice);
        else
            currentChunk = currentChunk.Add(slice);

        if (result.EndOfMessage && startChunk != null)
        {

            if (startChunk.Next == null)
                frame = new ReadOnlySequence<byte>(startChunk.Memory);
            else
                frame = new ReadOnlySequence<byte>(startChunk, 0, currentChunk, currentChunk.Memory.Length);

            startChunk = currentChunk = null; // Reset so we can accept new chunks from scratch.
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            frame = default;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.isUsingArrayPool)
        {
            var chunk = startChunk;

            while (chunk != null)
            {
                if (MemoryMarshal.TryGetArray(chunk.Memory, out var segment))
                    ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(segment.Array);

                chunk = (Chunk<byte>)chunk.Next;
            }
        }

        // Suppress finalization.
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

And then my class which contained the main loop like below - it has a `isUsingArrayPool` flag in the constructor of the class, so the caller can either free the memory up later manually, or not use array pool.

```
// Snipped the rest of the connection class.
byte[] GetBuffer()
{
    if (this.isUsingArrayPool)
        return ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(ReceiveChunkSize); // Rent a buffer.
    else
    {
        if(this.internalBufferIfArrayPoolNotUsed == null)
            this.internalBufferIfArrayPoolNotUsed = new byte[ReceiveChunkSize];

        return this.internalBufferIfArrayPoolNotUsed;
    }
}

async Task Loop(IEnumerable<string> tickers, Func<ReadOnlySequence<byte>,Task> dispatch, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{           
    while (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested == false)
    {
        var webSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
        webSocket.Options.KeepAliveInterval = this.keepAliveInterval;
        var resultProcessor = new WebSocketReceiveResultProcessor(this.isUsingArrayPool);

        try
        {
            this.logger.LogInformation($"Connecting.");
            await webSocket.ConnectAsync(uri, cancellationToken);           

            while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open && cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested == false)
            {
                var buffer = GetBuffer();
                var result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, cancellationToken);
                var isEndOfMessage = resultProcessor.Receive(result, buffer, out var frame);

                if (isEndOfMessage)
                {
                    if (frame.IsEmpty == true)
                        break; // End of message with no data means socket closed - break so we can reconnect.
                    else
                        await dispatch(frame);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebSocketException ex)
        {
            this.logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.logger.LogCritical(ex, ex.Message);
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            webSocket.Dispose();
            resultProcessor.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

If the array pool is used (`isUsingArrayPool = true`), the higher level functions in the `dispatch` call **must** return the buffers:

```
// Where frame is the ReadOnlySequence<byte> passed into dispatch function.
foreach (var chunk in frame)
{
    if (MemoryMarshal.TryGetArray(chunk, out var segment))
        ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(segment.Array);
}
```